# Storing, removing, and re-adding js events

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, mouseevent

I am looking for a way to remove click events, run some tests, and add the events back. From chrome dev console I've been using something like this:

```
// store events here
var clickEvents = [];

// remove all click events
getEventListeners(document)["click"].forEach( function(event) {
    clickEvents.push(event);
    document.removeEventListener("click", event.listener, event.useCapture);
});

// do stuff

// re-add events
clickEvents.forEach( function(event) {
    document.addEventListener("click", event.listener, event.useCapture);
});
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to do the same directly from the website code, without using the browser dev console, since `getEventListeners` only works on the console, this code won't work if executed from the website code.